# List defined preprocessor symbols for C#

Tags: c#

When running `dotnet`, `msbuild`, or `csc`, I want to output a list of defined preprocessor symbols, similar to `gcc -dM -E`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defined preprocessor symbols are listed in a proprety called `DefineConstants`. To echo them, you could add a target to your project file like the following:

```
<Target Name="EchoDebugInfo" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Just before building, current compile defines are $(DefineConstants)"></Message>
</Target>
```

In my test run (using `dotnet build` with no extra parameters), this printed:

```
Just before building, current compile defines are TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP2_2
```

Note that if you omit `Importance="high"`, the importance of the message [defaults to "normal"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/message-task?view=vs-2019#parameters), which won't show in the default verbosity of `dotnet build`. Setting `Importance="high"` allowed me to get the output without changing the default verbosity of the `dotnet build` command.

BTW, if you try to define the `BeforeBuild` target as suggested in the [Visual Studio docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2019), you'll discover that it doesn't work if you're using the new .Net Core-style projects (e.g., `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`). This is because the SDK project is auto-imported *after* your project file, so you'll see something similar to this message in the build logs:

> Overriding target "BeforeBuild" in project "/home/rmunn/path/to/project/Project.fsproj" with target "BeforeBuild" from project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets".

And then your `BeforeBuild` target doesn't work. There's a note in the MSDN docs that explains this (emphasis in original):

> SDK-style projects have an implicit import of targets *after the last line of the project file*. This means that you cannot override default targets unless you specify your imports manually as described in [How to: Use MSBuild project SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2019).

If you need full control over when the SDK project is imported, then that's the way to go. But for this simple use case, I prefer to define my own target and use `BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"` to place it in the correct place in the build order.

Comment: BTW, this does not work with `csc` as `csc` doesn't use the project file. But you're usually more interested in seeing the defined symbols *as seen by `dotnet build`* anyway, so I didn't try to find a solution that would work with `csc`.

Comment: As seen by `dotnet build` is definitely what I care about

Comment: Note that this will output one line per `TargetFramework`, which means if you're targeting multiple you'll get multiple lines of output. I suggest adding `$(TargetFramework)` to the output message to see which constants are defined for which TFM.